# Configure Yahoo mail account to Windows Phone 8

Tags: email

I've decided to write this in case someone will really needed cause I had to spent lots of time before my Yahoo mail account was synchronized with a Windows Phone 8.

**What is the problem?**

When add yahoo mail account to all accounts to synchronize with windows phone 8 -> no connection is made and no mail are synched with you phone.

**Reason:**

When you set up account sync with Phone using Yahoo option -> it uses POP3 methode to get mail by default and you cannot change this in settings. So every time you're trying to connet to mail using POP3 it does not connects. POP3 protocol is included ONLY on premium account YAHOO. That's why it's not synched (in case if you do not have premium account already)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution:**

*To set up you account:*

1. Delete previously created accont yahoo. If it is not available wait
   before synch process is finished and "Attention required" is shown.
   Then you can delete this.
2. In the params of you phone go to "mail accounts" and "add
   service"->"other".
3. Enter your Yahoo mail and password -> "Next"
4. Set up settings as follows   •Incoming Server: imap.mail.yahoo.com
   •Outgoing Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
   •Incoming Port: 993 (requires SSL)
   •Outgoing Port: 465 (requires SSL/TLS) - if this does not work try port 25
   •User name: full email address (for example, bill@yahoo.com or
   bill@rocketmail.com)   •Password: the password you log in to Yahoo!
   with.
5. ***IMPORTANT*** to sent IMAP4 settings for method. This will allow you to sync without having premium  account
6. Save it.

It should work now!

Hope it helps,

Andrew