# Yahoo account info is incorrect- lumia 540

Tags: lumia, sync, yahoo

I am trying to add a new yahoo account in my windows lumia 540, but I am getting the error message "Yahoo account info is incorrect",

I tried the below methods,

1. Signed in using the other option
2. [Configure Yahoo mail account to Windows Phone 8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/configure-yahoo-mail-account-to-windows-phone-8)
3. [Yahoo Mail stopped syncing](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12389/yahoo-mail-stopped-syncing)

**Result for the above 3**

I was getting the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following and it worked.

1. Enable [2 step verification](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN6050.html) in yahoo account.
2. Generate [app specific password](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2080.html) and in the list of apps select "Other" and clicked on generate.
3. Enter the 12 digit code in place of password.

Now it will login successfully.