# yahoo mail on phone quit

Tags: email, yahoo

Yahoo mail on my windows htc 7.5 phone suddenly stopped syncing Jan 2016. I can access yahoo mail on all other devices (laptop, desktop, etc.) Just not on Windows phone. I've tried deleting, then re-adding mail acct on phone, taking out battery awhile...Nothing works. Always "error" or "attention required" message on phone. Please help.

Comment: Is 2 step verification enabled ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12503/106

Answer (score 5):

From my answer here, https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12512/19301

> 1. Enable [2 step verification](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN6050.html) in yahoo account.
> 2. Generate [app specific password](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2080.html) and in the list of apps select "Other" and clicked on generate.
> 3. Enter the 12 digit code in place of password.
>
> Now it will login successfully.