# Email and Download pictures issues

Tags: email, photos, 7.5, windows-10

I have a HTC Trophy phone with Windows 7.5. I am unable to download my pictures from my phone to my computer. Actually when I connect my phone via USB cable it does not show on my PC at all. My PC is Windows 10.  In addition my Yahoo email is no longer working, giving an error code of 800C0000. I am able to sign into any computer with my Windows Live account, but not on my phone. I have tried my phone service provider who could not help. Does anyone know of any way to correct any or all of these issues? I seriously need some of the pictures for a work project!
Thanks for reading this!

Comment: It is advised to ask your problems as two seperate questions as you have two seperate problems.

Comment: is there a reason you haven't upgraded to 7.8?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the Yahoo mail problem can be found [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12511/yahoo-mail-on-phone-quit). The solution is,

1. Enable [2 step verification](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN6050.html) in yahoo account.
2. Generate [app specific password](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2080.html) and in the list of apps select "Other" and clicked on generate.
3. Enter the 12 digit code in place of password.

Now it will login successfully.

---

Regarding your problem connecting your phone with Windows 10 PC follow these steps,

1. Disconnect your phone.
2. Open [device manager](http://www.tenuser.com/spec/devmgmt.htm).
3. Locate your phone.
4. Uninstall the phone driver.

[image]

5. Restart your PC.
6. Re-connect your phone.

Comment: I tried the 2 step verification before posting my issues. I guess I should have stated that.  I listed the problems in the same post because I feel that somehow they are related....But maybe I didn't mention the biggest issue which may be the root of the others. When I connect my phone via USB to any computer (I have tried 3 now) it does nto recognize my phone. I believe that is why I can't download pictures or update my Windows version. Not sure if or if so how this may affect the email.

Comment: @Wanda You oculd have mentioned it though. Does Windows Recovery tool detect you phone? If not it is probably a hardware fault on datacard or pin.